# Warnings about Connection.Dispose

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am getting few warnings, all about disposing `SqlConnection`.

This is my code:

```
public Dictionary<string, MyObject> GetGrpDataFromDB(string btnGrp)
{
    Globals glob = new Globals();
    using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection((glob.Comms())))
    {
        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT BrzaGrupaBroj,BrzaGrupaNaziv,BrzaGrupaColor FROM BrzaGrupaGUI", Connection);

        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                Connection.Open();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Connection.Close();
            }

            var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                var newObject = new MyObject(row);
                myDictionary.Add(newObject.brzaGrpBr , newObject);
            }
            return myDictionary;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exact Warning:

```
Warning CA2202  Object 'Connection' can be disposed more than once in method 'GetGrpRowsDB.GetGrpDataFromDB(string)'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.
```

How can I dispose the `SqlConnection` only once, so that I can get rid of those warnings? :)

EDIT:

I tried without using Try Catch Finnaly, but even then I am getting exact same warning. maybe I am looking in wrong place?

```
 public Dictionary<string, MyObject> GetGrpDataFromDB(string btnGrp)
    {

        Globals glob = new Globals();
        using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection((glob.Comms())))
        {
            SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT BrzaGrupaBroj,BrzaGrupaNaziv,BrzaGrupaColor FROM BrzaGrupaGUI", Connection);


            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();


                Connection.Open();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                Connection.Close();


                var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>();
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    var newObject = new MyObject(row);
                    myDictionary.Add(newObject.brzaGrpBr , newObject);
                }
                return myDictionary;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No need to close manually it as `using` statement closes/disposes the underlying resource for you.

Comment: DataAdapters can open and close the connection for you, so you don't need the `Connection.Open();` line.  Your function isn't using the btnGrp parameter.

Comment: @LarsTech good catch on btnGrp (that was remains of bad sql prone injection code) Thanks

Comment: If you plan on putting that in your sql query, make sure to use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IDisposable` interface is specifically documented as saying that all implementations are expected to support being disposed any number of times, and that they shouldn't error when calling `Dispose` (even on repeated calls).  They are expected to error of you use them after disposing of them, but not if you dispose of them more than once.  If that object actually throws an object disposed exception on the second dispose call the bug would be in that class, not yours (and I strongly doubt the authors of the connection class have written such a bug).

There's no particular reason to dispose of the resource multiple times.  By all means, remove the redundant disposal to avoid the redundancy if you want.  (In this case, closing the connection make the most sense to remove, that way any problems creating the command or adapter don't leak the connection.)

This isn't an actual compiler warning, it's just a code analysis statement, many of which are unfortunately not actually indications of things that are problematic.  I suggest just disabling that warning, as it's just flat out wrong.

Comment: Interesting.... more on that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tilovell/2014/02/12/the-worst-code-analysis-rule-thats-recommended-ca2202/

Comment: I am new to C#, and I wonder, is it good practice with using block also use try catch finnaly? Or that won't really matter (mostly because, catching exceptions)

Comment: You don't need the finally, the `using` will do a `Dispose()` call within a `finally` block for you.  That's what it does.  And, for most objects that have a `Close()` call, the two calls (`Close()` and `Dispose()`) are equivalent

Comment: @Bodul The only difference here is that with the added close you're able to close the connection before the connection reaches the end of the using, specifically, before you do some processing on the results.  If that was important to you, it'd probably have been better to just adjust the scope of the `using` so that your processing of the data table was *after* you closed the using on the various disposable resources, although adding in the `Close` that you did certainly works.  But the only real problems from being redundant is that it's redundant, not that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Flydog57 - so try..catch without finally block since using will make sure to close and dispose. And i can still use catch for exceptions?   Great, Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Servy, this is likely just a Code Analysis warning, and can be ignored.

Now for some off-topic suggested improvements to your code:

1. Avoid using abbreviations in your identifiers. It makes your code harder to read and understand.
2. You can chain `using` statements together to reduce unnecessary nesting.
3. `SqlCommand` implements `IDisposable` too; it needs a `using` statement.
4. You can use `var` when the type is obvious.
5. The `btnGroup` parameter isn't used, it can be removed.

Here's what your code looks like with a little refactoring:

```
public Dictionary<string, MyObject> GetGroupDataFromDatabase()
{
    var globals = new Globals();

    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection((globals.Comms()))) // If you can, I'd rename Comms too.
    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT BrzaGrupaBroj, BrzaGrupaNaziv, BrzaGrupaColor FROM BrzaGrupaGUI", sqlConnection))
    using (var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        // Don't forget sqlConnection.Open() could throw an 
        // InvalidOperationException, and you should handle that scenario
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex) 
        {
            // Do something with the exception, like logging
        }

        var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>();

        foreach (var row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            var newObject = new MyObject(row);
            myDictionary.Add(newObject.brzaGrpBr, newObject);
        }

        return myDictionary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoter: please let me know how I can improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can get rid of the finally block in your code. you wrapped the creation of the `Connection` object in a using statement, so when the scope leaves the using block, it will automatically dispose of the `Connection` variable for you.

you either use the using statement or try/catch/finally to close the connection, but not both

Comment: But even without finnaly block, I am getting same warning.

Comment: You removed the `Connection.Close()` too? The `using` block will close the connection so you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: Code like `using (someDisposableObj) { /* code */ }` is exactly equivalent to `try { /* code */ } finally { ((IDisposable) someDisposableObj).Dispose(); }`.  The Using statement guarantees disposal of your object

Comment: Yes, after removing Connection.Close there are no more warnings.

Comment: @Flydog57 not *exactly*, but close. You're missing the null check. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement#remarks).